# sqlserver - mysql transfer datetime issue

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datetime

I am implementing an app to migrate data from `sqlserver` to `mysql` and experiencing a problem.

When it comes to `SQLSERVER DATETIME (e.g 1999-08-01 00:00:00.000)` to be transfered to MYSQL.
MYSQL returns a ***syntax error near 00:00:00.000***.

Answer (score 0):

This format should work for MySQL. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3120).

Comment: It works now. My query generator was generating datetime as 2000-03-17 00:00:00.000, I changed it to '2000-03-17 00:00:00.000'